# SDE books for non-mathematicians

Tags: book-recommendation, stochastic-differential-equations

I want to learn about SDEs. Most books on this topic are very dry & mathematical with no intuition at all. Can someone recommend a good book or courses for non-mathematicians? I am from computer science. I need a reference for dummies.

Comment: [An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/1470410540/ref=dbs_a_w_dp_1470410540) by Evans appears to be one of the more accessible books on this topic. Having said that, I wish someone could just tell me in a few paragraphs what the main idea behind stochastic differential equations is. It seems to be a rather poorly explained subject. I've been hanging out here for years and I still haven't learned the basic ideas. It can't be that hard. Is there a notion of the derivative in stochastic calculus?

Comment: I found this to be useful, might be too basic for you https://qr.ae/pNjWFl

Comment: Hey! I found the following books to be useful: Stochastic Differential Equations by Bernt Oksendal  (https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Differential-Equations-Introduction-Applications/dp/3540047581) and Introduction to Stochastic Integration by Hui-Hsiung Kuo (https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Stochastic-Integration-Universitext-Hui-Hsiung/dp/0387287205), the latter being a little more technical and dry in exposition.

Comment: thanks will check them out

Comment: The script [Forsyth: "... without agonizing pain"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Epaforsyt/agon.pdf) contains a good introduction to SDE and their numerics in the first third of its 120 pages.